# is gmail account mandatory for Google cloud messaging

Tags: android, push-notification, gmail, google-cloud-messaging

We are going to use Google Cloud Messaging service in one of our enterprise mobile application. The target device may be BYOD/company owned devices. Is it mandatory for devices to register/log in to Google account (using somaaddress at G mail dot com) for using the GCM push notification services?

Comment: An android device has to be registered with a valid google account in order to receive notifications (because of Google Play Services). The email for this google account doesn't have to be a gmail address.

Comment: Not anymore. See answer (I have tried it also and it works, without registering e-mail on Android 4.4.4 though I had to update Google Play Services manually first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the official docs, a Google account is required for GCM to work only for pre-3.0 devices :

> It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

([Source](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html))

That said, from a discussion on the [android-gcm group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/ecG-RfH-Aso), one of the GCM developers at Google implied that if you register to GCM using the new Google Play Services library, you don't need a Google account even for pre-3.0 devices (Froyo and Gingerbread) :

> **Froyo and Gingerbread registration is implemented in
>   GoogleServicesFramework, using the Google account for registration**.
>   This has resulted in a lot of auth errors for people where the account
>   was not in a good state.
>
> **Starting with ICS, GCM doesn't depend or uses the Google account** - you
>   can use it before you add an account or without any accounts.
>
> **The "Play Services" update is implementing the new scheme on all
>   devices** - but it seems a small number of devices have problems with
>   this, we're investigating - but the numbers are far lower than those
>   with the old scheme.

Comment: So essentially if the user logs into their phone, i.e. at initial boot you must input a Google account, then this requirement is satisfied?